# How can I delete a big file from all commits? .git folder is too big

Tags: git

I have a repo with a big size .git folder (around 350mb) and I want to reduce it, because every time someone made a clone (even using the --single-branch flag) it lasts more than 3 minutes in pulling all the data.

After using `du -h | sort -h` I found the culprit and deleted it (it was a sql dump file at `app/db.dump`):

```sh
# Some files skipped
...
30M     ./public
30M     ./public/assets
338M    ./app
354M    ./.git
354M    ./.git/objects
354M    ./.git/objects/pack
729M    .
```

Now I'm trying to delete that big file that someone pushed by mistake from all the commits on the repo, to reduce its size. But I haven't yet succeeded.

I've already tried with the following commands but they are not working for me, the .git folder still preserves it size:

```sh
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch app/db.dump" HEAD
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

I'm using `git version 2.26.2`.

Hope someone can shed me some light on this. Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks! @Donat and @Tom, the problem was that I tried to reflog and prune without previously making a commit to remove the big file. This was stated after running `bfg.jar`, which gave me this clue in its output.

After doing a commit to remove the big file, I re-ran `bfg.jar` and the .git folder's size was finally shrunk

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/10533011 .

Comment: Use bfg https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below. In effect your intention is to remove that file from every single commit where it may be referenced..

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-BIG FILE" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git push --force --verbose --dry-run
git push --force
```